# How to check for a text (span) and bord a div

Tags: javascript

I have a problem making this script work right.

I need to find the text "1" or "1 giv".

That is what I'm trying right now:

```
addEventListener();
function addEventListener(){
    $('div.giv:has(span.g-icon:contains(1))').each(function(){
       $(this).css("border","4px solid red");


});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/goeabx7d/1/

Would appreciate if someone could help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('span.g-icon').each(function(){
        if ($(this).html() == '1' | $(this).html() == '1 coal') {
            $(this).closest("div.giv").css("border","4px solid red");
        }
        if ($(this).html() == '0' | $(this).html() == '0 coal') {
            $(this).closest("div.giv").css("border","4px solid yellow");
        }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/goeabx7d/3/